# Vuex dispatch running infinity

Tags: vuex, href, vuejs3

Please, can anybody tell me why this function is running in an infinite loop?

```
  <a:href="authenticationChoice(currentView['name'])" > **(Here. Keeps executing)**
                <img
                  class="w-12 inline-block align-middle"
                  :src="showAuthenticationIcon(currentView['gitType'])"         
                />
  </a>
```

This is the direct function being call to dispatch the vuex action.

```
authenticationChoice(recieved) {
      this.$store.state.gitSourceAuthenticationChoice = recieved;

      this.$store.dispatch("gitSourceAuthenticationURL").then((response) => {
        this.navigationURL = response["oauth2_redirect"];
        console.log(this.navigationURL)
       
      });
      return this.navigationURL;
    },
```

This is the action function in the vuex file

```
  async gitSourceAuthenticationURL({ state }) {
      return await axios
        .get(`${Config.ApiUrl}/auth/login/${state.gitSourceAuthenticationChoice}`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.data
        }).catch((error) => {
          //console.log(error.data)
        });
    },
```

Comment: Two things, 1st href should always be a link, you are breaking web accessibility here, not suggested don't do it. 2nd if you want to execute some function on click, use button and probably , if you use button your issue will be fixed. You bind property instead of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a property binding, so property bound to a value in `VueJS` is reactive, so every change detection, it ran and execute that.

That is why your method is getting called everything, when change detection is happening in `VueJS`.

```
<a:href="authenticationChoice(currentView['name'])" >
```

Kindly use click event or button to avoid this.

```
<button @click="authenticationChoice(currentView['name'])" >Text</button>
```

Or you can bind the click event on `<a>` tag, but you need to use `<a>` as button,  that's not very recommendable.